# How to get Skype Old Messages in Mac OS

Tags: skype

I want to get Skype messages of my particular contact around the years 2015 starting months.

If I manually do a scroll back then I reached in January 2018 and around one hour get passed and I become tired after this.

So, at last, I have decided to put question over here to get some expert suggestions into this.
I searched about this in Google but mostly the answers are related to the Windows platform.

Those reply not become useful to me.

Comment: It looks like Skype has a guide on this: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34894/how-do-i-export-my-skype-files-and-chat-history

Comment: Thank you I applied for the record of conversations and the status is in pending - at present the request is in processing

Comment: Today Skype has given me a 39mb JSON file with all conversion-related data. But no JSON Viewer can able to open this file and they all get hang. Do you know any viewer that can handle this much amount of data?

Comment: Not that I can think of off the top of my head. I know on Windows, you could write a PowerShell script to parse it using ConvertFrom-Json, but on mac, not sure. You might need to do some scripting or something like that. Alternatively, you can try to just open the file in a text editor and manually read through it.

Comment: Basically anyhow I have managed to open the file but one thing I noticed they sent the data up to the date that I have scrolled back manually in the Skype software after spending my almost 1 hour.